# is it possible to show progress dialog in tab bar activity

Tags: android

I want to show progress bar until tab bar is loaded is it possible to show progress dialog in tab bar activity? if possible can anybody give example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Put Progressbar for the child Activitys you are adding in TabHost .

First it will show progress bar of first activity in onCreate which you set as current activity.
then if you click on next tab it will show its progress dialog in its onCreate method.